# How to create a Kernel panic in RHEL without rebooting after panic

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, reboot, panic

I need to create kernel panic and I tried following

> sysctl kernel.panic=0 && echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger

When I ran the commands above. I see system always reboots. I need system to be in panic mode without rebooting

Answer (score 0):

**Use -w option** when you want to change a sysctl setting under RHEL.

Multiple commands example:

```
> sysctl -w kernel.panic="0"
> echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Notice that if you want to preserve kernel settings after reboot, it's always better to add them to the /etc/sysctl.conf file. However the quickly setting method maybe enough for your testing requirments.

**Also make sure you don't paste both commands "sysctl -w kernel.panic=0 echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger" together.** (I'm always giving this recommendation when i see multiple shell commands posted together, like i see in your question). Or use && operator to execute the next command like this:

Single line example:

```
sysctl -w kernel.panic="0" && echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Comment: I see that system is booting again. I don't  want system to reboot. I just wanted it to be in panic mode

Comment: It's working for me, on RHEL 7. I tested right now and i can see panic mode logs on the screen/no reboot. What RHEL version you are using?

Comment: I am using RHEL 7.5

Comment: Quite weird. I can't figure out what's wrong in your case.

Comment: After you execute sysctl -w kernel.panic="0" if you execute "sysctl kernel.panic" is 0 the value you see set?

Comment: sysctl -a |grep panic
debug.panic_on_rcu_stall = 0
fs.xfs.panic_mask = 0
kernel.hardlockup_panic = 0
kernel.hung_task_panic = 0
kernel.panic = 0
kernel.panic_on_oops = 1
kernel.panic_on_warn = 0

Comment: Quite same as mine after. Can't see much difference (except that i'm not using xfs but ext4 and using other things). Please if you ever solve this come with an update, i'm curious why this is happening...

# sysctl -a |grep panic
debug.panic_on_rcu_stall = 0
kernel.hardlockup_panic = 1
kernel.hung_task_panic = 0
kernel.panic = 0
kernel.panic_on_io_nmi = 0
kernel.panic_on_oops = 1
kernel.panic_on_unrecovered_nmi = 0
kernel.panic_on_warn = 0
kernel.softlockup_panic = 0
kernel.unknown_nmi_panic = 0
vm.panic_on_oom = 0